# Java soundApi recording error

Tags: java, audio, audio-recording, javasound

I am trying to record a 16khz mono-channel .wav file by using this code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Say what you see..");

        try {
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(
                    AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 16000, 8, 1, 4, 16000,
                    false);

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info))
                System.out.println("Line not Supported");
            final TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem
                    .getLine(info);
            targetLine.open();

            System.out.println("Recording");
            targetLine.start();

            Thread thread = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(
                            targetLine);
                    File audioFile = new File("record.wav");
                    try {
                        AudioSystem.write(audioStream,
                                AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, audioFile);
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("stopped recording");
                }

            };
            thread.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            targetLine.stop();
            targetLine.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it I always get this error:

```
Line not Supported
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 4 bytes/frame,  is supported.at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:476)at Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

ps: I tested it many times with different parameters for the AudioFormat It only worked when I tried these parameters which is stereo and 44.1khz

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,44100,16,2,4,44100,false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You must specify an `AudioFormat` that matches one of the formats supported by the `TargetDataLine`.

For example the microphone on my Mac supports:

[image: Supported Audio Formats]

'unknown sample rate' means the sample rate doesn't matter.

The main difference I see here is that you are specifying 4 bytes per frame, for 8 bit mono this should be 1 byte per frame.

Comment: @QA_Col See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39510109/2670892)